# Web service on windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-7, parallel-processing

I want to build web service with Visual studio and run it for testing and to try to access it from another computer in the same network,but it won't work,

i am using windows 7 on parallel and my ip v4 there is 10.0.0.11, and i am trying to connect from another computer to this address http://10.0.0.11:port/serviceName .

the is some thing that i did wrong?

Edit

i think the iis is working, i just pressed the play button is the visual studio to run it,if i try to open a browser in windows 7 and type there http://localhost:por/serviceName so it work.

the service is webform.
and by meaning not work is that when i try to use http://10.0.0.11:port/serviceName so the browser try to connect but not given me any thing and after couple of seconds he is timeout

Comment: Please extent your question: - What kind of service, WCF? - If so, how are you hosting your service, IIS, self-hosted? - What do mean by it wont work?

Comment: If IIS working? I think you need to post more data, there are too many things that could be happening..

Comment: i think the iis is working, i just pressed the play button is the visual studio to run it,if i try to open a browser in windows 7 and type there http://localhost:por/serviceName so it work.
 
the service is webform.
and by meaning not work is that when i try to use http://10.0.0.11:port/serviceName so the browser try to connect but not given me any thing and after couple of seconds he is timeout

Comment: @MTA, it definitely sounds like your not running in IIS, but in the Visual Studio development webserver. This server is automatically started when you run/debug your project, but it will only accept connections from localhost and not over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most likely not running your application in IIS. By default Visual Studio will launch it's development webserver (you should be able to find it in the system tray). The development webserver doesn't allow connections over the network, only connections through localhost are allowed because MS doesn't want you to use the development server for anything but development.

Visual Studio can run the application in IIS, right click on the project and open it's properties. On the Web tab you can select IIS instead of the Development Server.